A question about Milnor space
Let $G$ be a compact group and $H$ be a closed subgroup of $G$. I know that
if $G\rightarrow G/H$ is a principal $H$-bundle, then we can choose $E_{H}$ as $%
E_{G}$, where $E_{G}$ is the Milnor space of $G$. I know that it is not
always possible to choose $E_{H}$ as $E_{G}$.
What I'm wondering is that: the inclusion $E_{H}\subset E_{G}$ induces
cohomology monomorphism $H^{\ast }\left( E_{G}/H;%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211a} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Q}
%EndExpansion
\right) \rightarrow H^{\ast }\left( E_{H}/H;%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211a} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Q}
%EndExpansion
\right) =H^{\ast }\left( B_{H};%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211a} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Q}
%EndExpansion
\right) $?
Here $E_{G}/G$ denotes the orbit space of the action $G$ on the contractible
space $E_{G}$.

At least for Lie groups $EG/H$ is a $BH$: it is the quotient space of a contractible free right $H$-space. So the map you mention is an isomorphism, even with integral coefficients. Did you mean the map $H^(BG,\mathbb{Q})\to H^(BH,\mathbb{Q})$ instead?

@algori For Lie groups and for groups of finite-dimensional, it is clear. I am interested in the most general situation.
